# What obfuscator was used on java classes?

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, bytecode, decompiling, deobfuscation

Is there a way to know what kind of obfuscator was applied to a class?

I'm trying to decompile some classes with procyon cfr and other stuff but i noticed that all the strings passed to the class methods, especially the one  passed to some json classes or base64 classes are unreadble so i guess that they are obfuscated. Furthermore when trying to decompile many methods gave me errors leaving commented bytecode.

Thank you for your help

EDIT1: @Andreas_D To be more specific, i think that an obfuscator was used because all the strings like this:

```
this.af.add(JSON.endsWith((String)"Rgqrt", (int)(94 + -61)).toLowerCase());
```

or

```
this.af.add(JSON.endsWith((String)"\b##!(\t*?9+=", (int)(37 * 33)).toLowerCase());
```

Furthermore, in the decompiled code there are a lot of `goto -> label` statements. 
For this reason I think that a Zelix or a Stringer was used (even if I cannot see any zkm constant).
If this is the case, how can I go on with the decompiling process?

Comment: It's unclear to me where you suspect obfuscation. An example would be helpful.

Comment: Besides the unclear description of the symptoms, why do you think it would help to know “what kind of obfuscator was applied”?

Comment: Since most obfuscators handle string encryption differently you could look at how strings are decrypted and compare it to known patterns of obfuscators, As for the "commented bytecode" it means your decompiler failed to interpret the bytecode and restructure it as java. It's unlikely that that can be fixed.

Comment: @DisplayName how the comparison you talk about, can be performed? I'm at the beginning in this practice, so i don't know so much about decompiling and deobfuscating java, neither what r the best tools. Thanks for any help

Comment: You have to look at some samples so you can compare. Most obfuscators have free trials you can use to get some samples.

Comment: I managed to decode those strings as the decoding method itself is contained in a separate file. In this way i managed to decompile the method, cut and paste the code in a new program and now i'm going to use this new program to decode all the strings, starting from the decompiled version of the jars.